# Windows CE 5.0 Sound Issue

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, windows-ce, barcode-scanner

I have an asp.net application that runs on an MC9090 scan gun running Windows CE 5.0. I'm trying to play a sound on the scanner through the website. I used the code below to play the sound on the scanner, but it sounds like a crackle instead of the sound.

```
<embed id ="MyAudio" src="/External/MySound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" autostart="true" loop="false" />
```

Doing my research I found out that even when I play sounds directly on the scan gun, it doesn't play the sound instead it just plays the short crackle sound. So I thought the speakers were not working, but all the system sounds work fine. scan beeps and error beeps.

This is happening on two different scan guns. Does anyone have any ideas why even when I click on a wav file in the explorer on the scan gun it still doesn't play the sound correctly. Any help would be great.

EDIT: Also to clarify the system sounds are working on the scanner but nothing plays when called in the website, example:

```
System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all 9090s have working sound cards. Some need to have their core updated, which would involve contacting Motorola. You will still hear the scan and error beeps because all the 9090 devices have a built in beeper, that will take over if the speaker is not functioning properly.

The best way to test this would be to use OTL:

1. Go to the Application directory and launch OTL.exe
2. Click the "Test Apps" option.
3. Click the 'SelfTest" option.
4. Select "Speaker" and then click the "Start" button.
5. Select any wav file from the drop down and then listen. If it fails, you will see an error on the bottom of the form. Even on an error, you should still hear something because the device will attempt to use the Beeper instead.

If you don't have OTL, you could attempt to compare the wav files with another device that is known to have working sound.

If it is in fact an issue with the Speaker, you should contact Zebra because the device needs an update.

Also, to my understanding, the procedure you are calling will only attempt to play the wav file and not use the Beeper on failure. Which would cause the error of no sound to be played.